# my passphrase doesn't work I cant sent anything on bitcoin core - wallet

Tags: passphrase

my passphrase doesn't work I cant sent anything  on bitcoin core - wallet and I have $400.00 USD in bitcoins .. this is driving me crazy.. it was perfectly fine last Friday, now for the past 3 days I am not able to send or even change my passphrase ... this is ridiculous

Comment: I assume you’re looking for help? It’s not really clear what your exact question is. Are you sure you are using the correct password? Do you have a backup of the wallet (or a seed phrase)? Etc. The more info you provide, the better chance someone will be able to provide meaningful help.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to change my passphrase .. i tried sending some bitcoins but it wanted my passphrase i typed it in and said it was the wrong one .... it was fine a couple of days ago

Comment: The wallet is encrypted ...

Comment: I have a bitcoin wallet and was trying to send it over to it from bitcoin core .. that is how I found out my password wasn't working ... I tried the btcrecover and no luck ... I am at my wits end ...

Comment: Without the accurate password or the recovery phrase for the sending wallet, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your wallet-encryption passphrase doesn't work,

first you should check that you are not using a passphrase for a different wallet, not using a recovery-phrase as a wallet-passphrase, don't accidentally have caps-lock on or something silly but easy to overlook. Try variations of the passphrase.

ultimately you must use the safe copy you made of  your 12/18/24 recovery seed words or the safe copy you made of your private key and create a new wallet to regain control of your bitcoin as.